# Why view animation is not gone

Tags: android, android-animation

I am new in Android. I created ripple animation to hide view, but view do not gone.

```
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 150, 150, 200f, 0f);
anim.start();
```

I expect that view gone after animation is end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the right name for this animation is circular reveal.
You should add the listener to your animation and override method named as `onAnimationEnd`, then start an animation.
In the `onAnimationEnd` you should set visibility to the view.

```
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 150, 150, 200f, 0f);

anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});

anim.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the duration of the animation

```
Animator.setDuration(1000)
```

for example for 1000ms

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setAnimationListener` .

Follow this method:

```
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 150, 150, 200f, 0f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();

anima.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
       animation.cancel();
      //hide 
    }
});
```